# Python icalendar RRULE "until" property raising error

Tags: python, icalendar, rrule

I'm trying to use the RRULE function to make an event recur every Monday and Wednesday until a specific date. However, I'm not sure how to specify the end date for the 'until' property.

```
event.add('summary', 'Python meeting about calendaring')
event.add('dtstart', datetime(2022,1,16,8,4,0,tzinfo=eastern))
event.add('dtend', datetime(2022,1,16,9,5,5,tzinfo=eastern))
event.add('rrule', {'freq': 'weekly', 'until': ['2022', '5', '2'],'wkst': 'SU', 'byday': ['MO', 'WE']})
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> ValueError: You must use datetime, date, timedelta, time or tuple (for
> periods)

Comment: Try comparing the error message with the RFC5545 DATE, DATETIME  and RRULE until specs.https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5545#section-3.3.4.  Sorry can't help with python part

Answer (score 1):

could not find anything in the docs, but it seems the `UNTIL` rule needs to entered as a `datetime` and not as a list of integers. The following code

```
from icalendar import Event
from datetime import datetime
ev = Event()
ev.add('dtstart', datetime(2013,11,22,8))
ev.add('dtend', datetime(2013,11,22,12))
ev.add('rrule', {'until': datetime(2022,5,2),'freq': 'daily','wkst': 'SU','byday': ['MO', 'WE']})
print(ev.to_ical().decode("utf-8"))
```

> BEGIN:VEVENT
> DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20131122T080000
> DTEND;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20131122T120000
> RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20220502T000000;BYDAY=MO,WE;WKST=SU
> END:VEVENT